# Protected express API access using Kinde

Tags: express, authentication, next.js

I am building a web app with next.js and a mobile app with react native. Both apps use my backend using node.js and express. For authentication I try to use Kinde (https://kinde.com/). While I manage to authenticate users successfully in my next.js app (have not tried it in react native) and protect my backend API routes by using also Kinde, I struggle to access my protected API routes from the next.js app even though both use Kinde.

I can get an accessToken (among others) from Kinde in next via:

```
import {getKindeServerSession} from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import Link from "next/link";

export default async function Home() {
  const {
    getAccessToken,
    getBooleanFlag,
    getFlag,
    getIntegerFlag,
    getOrganization,
    getPermission,
    getPermissions,
    getStringFlag,
    getUser,
    getUserOrganizations,
    isAuthenticated
  } = getKindeServerSession();

  [...]
}
```

But it seems like none of the options above fit with what Kinde expects in an express server.

Neither via "protectRoute":

```
const { protectRoute } = require("@kinde-oss/kinde-node-express");    
   
app.get("/admin", protectRoute, (req, res) => {
   res.send("Welcome to the admin area");
});
```

Nor via "verifier":

```
const {jwtVerify} = require("@kinde-oss/kinde-node-express");
const verifier = jwtVerify("https://<your_kinde_subdomain>.kinde.com");

app.get("/some-route", verifier, (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.user);
});
```

Can someone describe a way how I can access my protected routes?

Answer (score 0):

The result of the getAccessToken function is the destructured JSON object of the token, you **cannot** use this or any of the values to send directly to your server for authentication. The safe way is to get the cookie value of the access_token and send that in every request to your server routes that need authentication.

In your NextJS app get the raw access_token cookie value and set it as a header in your request

```
const accessToken = cookies().get('access_token')?.value;
const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
requestHeaders.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
```

On your server you can create your own verifier with

```
import {JwtRsaVerifier} from 'aws-jwt-verify';
const verifier = JwtRsaVerifier.create({
  issuer, // this is most likely https://xxx.kinde.com
  audience: audience || null,
  jwksUri: `${issuer}/.well-known/jwks.json`
});
```

And make sure your audience is the same as the one in your NextJS env variable (KINDE_AUDIENCE=https://xxx.kinde.com/api) with the management API enabled.

Now you can simply do this in a middleware, getting the token sent by NextJS and parsing it

```
try {
   const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
   const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];

   const payload = await verifier.verify(token);
} catch {
   // error decoding token
}
```

`payload` will return the destructured JWT where you can check for the destructured token values

Comment: getAccessToken provides me with an object that includes a property called "jti", which appears to be related to a JWT. Even after carefully reading the link you've provided, it is still unclear to me what to do on the express server.

Comment: Did you set your audience in the env file?

Comment: Edited my post with more details.

Comment: While I understand your approach for the express server in your edited post, I would assume that there must be a direct solution provided by Kinde instead of extracting the access token from cookies.

Comment: Currently there is none, I confirmed with Kinde support, they told me to just extract the cookie.